# How can I request refresh token api before jwt token expires in React.js project

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, jwt, refresh-token

How can I request refresh token api before jwt token expires in React.js project.
If my token time is 1 minute, I need to renew the token after 59 seconds.
If I don't renew within 1 minute, my token becomes useless.
Technologies I use
react hooks,
context api

Answer (score 0):

The preferred / reliable option is to allow the access token to expire and handle 401s by retrying the API request with a new access token.

See [this code](https://github.com/curityio/web-oauth-via-bff/blob/main/code/spa/src/api/apiClient.ts#L26) for an example of how a reliable client calls APIs.

If interested in how this feels from a performance viewpoint, run my [Online SPA](https://authguidance.com/home/code-samples-quickstart/), sign in, then click these options:

- Expire Access Token
- Reload Data

In some setups there can be more subtle ways for your UI to receive 401s, such as token signing certificate renewal and load balancing flips - so I always recommend that clients code this retry logic.

Comment: api does not support this event. I need to make a request before the token expires.